# ssh server asks for password before I even set the password on wsl

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to set up an ssh server on my windows 10 machine through WSL (I'm using WSL 1 if this makes a difference), running ubuntu.

So I followed [this tutorial](https://www.illuminiastudios.com/dev-diaries/ssh-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux/). Basically I installed open-ssh from the command line, and I created a new user by adding `AllowUsers <yourusername>` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I also made sure the firewall was allowing connections to port 22.

Then I went to my other laptop (the one I'm trying to ssh from), which is a mac, and typed `ssh 192.168.X.X` which is my windows' machine private ip (it's static btw). Both my windows machine (the ssh server), and my mac machine (the ssh client) are on the same network, which is why I'm sshing using a private ip.

For some reason I'm asked to input a password, but I don't know what password I should use. I tried my windows machine login password, as well as my WSL admin password (the one I use when executing sudo commands). Both didn't work. I'm pretty sure this is something obvious because I haven't found any solution on this online, so it must be something really stupid that doesn't even need to be asked...

I also tried `ssh <yourusername>@192.168.X.X` where `<yourusername>` is the one I added in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but I was also required to input a password.

Edit:

I tried `ssh localhost` but got

`@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY! Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)! It is also possible that a host key has just been changed. The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is SHA256:xxxxx.`

`Please contact your system administrator. Add correct host key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message. Offending ECDSA key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1 remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "localhost" ECDSA host key for localhost has changed and you have requested strict checking. Host key verification failed.`

(I put xxx instead of the fingerprint and user instead of my username for privacy). I also stopped my ssh server and closed my open port because I'm worried something bad is happening, which is really weird.

Comment: Does no one here know? I'd assume that this would be some little mistake I'm doing with setting the server, and not something difficult.

Comment: As a first troubleshooting step, from WSL, try `ssh localhost` and see if you can access it there with your WSL user's password.  What happens?

Comment: Okay this is really weird. I tried `ssh localhost` but got

Comment: Your comment didn't quite come through - Perhaps it was in angled brackets?  Usually better to edit the new information into the question anyway, though.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry it was too long so I edited the post. I don't know what is happening...

Comment: No worries.  Okay, let's start with the host key.  Give me a few minutes to get the right commands to check it.  This most likely isn't a big deal since we can confirm the host keys "locally" in WSL.

Comment: Thank you dude this really helps, I found it really weird that someone would be "eavesdropping" on me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134715/discussion-between-notthedr01ds-and-moonlessnightss).

Comment: The passphrase used is the passphrase of the local account on the remote server for whatever user is SSHing in, or the encryption passphrase of the SSH key if using PKI _(user passphrase logins are not secure for SSH, use an SSH key and encrypt the private key, allowing you to freely copy the key between devices with no concern of t being compromised - if you have a YubiKey or other 2FA hardware key, you can store the SSH key on it in the A[uthorization] key slot)_. It's recommended to [harden](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSH) the default `sshd_config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and chat, we determined that the *Windows* OpenSSH server was also running.  Since it also defaults to port 22, the one that was running in WSL/Ubuntu wasn't able to bind to that port.

So when you `ssh`'d from the Mac to your "WSL", it was really connecting to the Windows SSH server.  It was expecting the Windows username and password.

Since you had your WSL username in the Mac's ssh_config, and that username doesn't exist under Windows, it was denying all passwords.  It wasn't really that the password wasn't correct as much as the username.

The solution, since this is WSL1, was fairly straightforward -- Just:

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Uncomment the Port and change it to 2222 or another unused port
# Save and exit
sudo service ssh restart
```

And we confirmed this with `ssh -p 2222 localhost`.

After that, it also worked from the Mac using the proper port number.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! (can't upvote your answer due to low reputation).

Comment: @MoonlessNightss No worries - The accept is good, and I think your upvote will take effect when you get to 20 rep.  Glad I could help!